# Scala Tuple type inference in Java

Tags: java, scala

This is probably a very noobish question, but I was playing a bit with Scala/Java interaction, and was wondering how well did Tuples play along.

Now, I know that the `(Type1, Type2)` syntax is merely syntactic sugar for `Tuple2<Type1, Type2>`, and so, when calling a Scala method that returns a Tuple2 in a plain Java class, I was expecting to get a return type of `Tuple2<Type1, Type2>`

For clarity, my Scala code:

```
def testTuple:(Int,Int) = (0,1)
```

Java code:

```
Tuple2<Object,Object> objectObjectTuple2 = Test.testTuple();
```

It seems the compiler expects this to be of parameterized types `<Object,Object>`, instead of, in my case, `<Integer,Integer>` (this is what I was expecting, at least).

Is my thinking deeply flawed and is there a perfectly reasonable explanation for this?

OR

Is there a problem in my Scala code, and there's a way of being more... explicit, in the cases that I know will provide an API for Java code?

OR

Is this simply a limitation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Int` is Scala's integer type, which [is a value class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified_types.html), so it gets special treatment.  It is different from `java.lang.Integer`.  You can specify `java.lang.Integer` specifically if that's what you need.

```
[dlee@dlee-mac scala]$ cat SomeClass.scala 
class SomeClass {
  def testIntTuple: (Int, Int) = (0, 1)
  def testIntegerTuple: (java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer) = (0, 1)
}

[dlee@dlee-mac scala]$ javap SomeClass
Compiled from "SomeClass.scala"
public class SomeClass implements scala.ScalaObject {
  public scala.Tuple2<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object> testIntTuple();
  public scala.Tuple2<java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer> testIntegerTuple();
  public SomeClass();
}
```

Comment: So, `Int` is not an ordinary Scala class? (If it would be, then the `Int` version should have been compiled into `scalaTuple2<scala.Int, scalaInt>` or something similar, no?)

Comment: Correct. From [the scaladocs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Int.html): "`Int` is a member of the value classes, those whose instances are not represented as objects by the underlying host system." The [page describing unified types](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified_types.html) may better explain it.

Comment: Great answer @dave, thank you, that makes perfect sense since Int can't be magically translated into a Java class, I was assuming it would be translated into Integer.

Comment: @pcalcao - It _is_ translated into `Integer`, but it is typed as `Object`.

Comment: @RexKerr - Now that is interesting. The compiler's already doing all the hard work of boxing/unboxing. I wonder why it doesn't type it as `java.lang.Integer` when it's a type parameter.

Comment: @dave It did that at one point, but that results in bugs that are impossible to avoid. Related, I think, to generic classes which are overridden with `Int`-specific ones, and the consequences that has on type signatures for fields and methods.